# Calculate difference in seconds between two dates in various SQL databases (MySQL, Oracle, H2)

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, h2

I need to calculate the difference in seconds between two dates in SQL. The problem is that the same query will be executed in different environments, with different database engines.

There is MySQL locally, Oracle in production environment and H2 for tests.

I wrote a query using `TIME_TO_SEC` function, it worked perfectly, but then the integration tests failed, because there I had H2 instead of MySQL. I also tried to use `DATEDIFF` function, but its implementation is different in all of these databases.

Is there a possibility to write a single, universal query for all these databases?

Comment: I dont know. Have you tried?

Comment: How can you maintain your application running perfectly developing in one DB and having a different one in production? Just praying?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding! You have a MYSQL database as a test database, a Oracle database for a production environment and H2 for something else. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, basically there are three different databases I need to think about. I wrote a query using ``TIME_TO_SEC``, it worked perfectly, but then the integration tests failed, because there I had H2 instead of MySQL. I also tried to use ``DATEDIFF`` function, but its implementation is different in all of these databases.

Comment: That is a totally crazy environment

Comment: No... you ought to use the same database for development, testing and production. You could try writing a user-defined function in each language with a common function declaration to wrap the database-specific methods for subtracting dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `60 + extract(SECOND FROM (b.created_ts)) - extract(SECOND FROM a.created_ts)` and it works for all those databases.

Comment: It's not all right, you are comparing just the seconds part of dates. How about minutes, hours, days ?

Answer (score -1):

I only can try testing in Oracle. This help you?

```
SELECT ( SYSDATE - (SYSDATE-1)) * 60 * 60 * 24
  FROM DUAL
```